# Как перенести часть блока на новую строку?

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо чтобы `clear` вместе с блоком `input` до него располагались на новой строке (После ссылки на фотографию). Проблема в том, что всё что находится на картинке и даже чуть больше это один большой блок field, но `input` блок и `clear` в нём никак не связаны, поэтому например `truncatewords` не помогает

`html`

```
{% for field in display_form %}
    <div class="form-group">
         {% if field|field_type == "CheckboxInput" %}
              <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                   style="display: inline-block;">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
              <div style="width: 1em; display: inline-block"> {{ field }} </div>
         {% else %}
              <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"><div>{{ field.label_tag }}</div></label>
              <div>{{ field }}</div>
         {% endif %}
         {% if field.help_text %}
              <p class="hint-text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
         {% endif %}
     </div>
     {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
               <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось решить эту проблему. Я просто переписал фильтр `truncatewords` так, чтобы он переносил строку не на любое слово, а только после расширений файлов фотографий (.jpg, .png и тд)